# dynamicaly generate multiple highcharts and append to jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I have 2 charts: a linechart and a donut chart which uses highcharts. These charts are linked to each other. So when either of the chart is hovered the relevant point on the charts are highlighted.

You can check my demo here http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/rmxjmsy1/2/

Now what I'm trying to achieve is, I have several tabs, which are separated to 7,14,30 days..on each tab the line chart will have different values based on the duration. So when the user clicks on the tabs, that person will be able to see the chart within that period without losing the highlighting point of the charts.

I was figuring out some methods and I though when the user clicks on a tab, post the duration and do the relevant calculations and append the result to the chart container.

```
$('#ui-id-2').click(function(){

    $.ajax
    ({ 
        url: '<?php echo base_url('index.php/chart')?>',
        data: {"duration": 14},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(result)
        {
            $( "#container3" ).append(result);
        }
    });
});
```

and on the PHP I echoed the linechart code. I'm not sure if its a correct approach but I wanted see if it works. But unfortunately it didn't draw the chart.

Can someone tell me what would be the best way to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "person will be able to see the chart within that period without losing the highlighting point of the charts." The points get highlighted if the user hovers over them - but when he is clicking a tab then the points are not highlighted. Also, why do you want to append result to the container (you want to append a new chart?) instead of updating data/series?